# How can I let IDA execute int 2D so that execution transfers to the exception handler function?

Tags: ida, anti-debugging

I'm reversing a program that dynamically loads [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and uses it to set a function as an exception handler. It then calls `int 2D` - so that execution transfers to the function only when the program is not being debugged.

I want to see how the function behaves dynamically - specifically because I'm having trouble understanding how it works with its `EXCEPTION_POINTER*` parameter - but I can't really do that because execution won't even transfer there while I'm debugging.

How can I make IDA execute int 2D so that I can see execution transfer to the exception handler function and see its behavior dynamically?

I tried following the advice in [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/handling-int-2d-anti-debugger-technique-in-ida-pro?rq=1), but it didn't help: changing `0x2DCD` to `0x2DFF` had the exact same effect - the program crashed.

Comment: Could you post a relevant excerpt of the assembly?

Comment: you could also try one of IDAStealth or ScyllaHide for IDA plugins.

Answer (score 2):

The KERNEL32.UnhandledExceptionFilter() is special, because it checks for the presence of a debugger, and refuses to call the process-defined UnhandledExceptionFilter() if one is present.  In order to reach the process-defined routine, you need to set a breakpoint on NTDLL.NtQueryInformationProcess(), and check for these parameters on the stack: -1, 7, a pointer, 4, 0.  When you see it, you can step over the function, change the return value to -1, and resume execution.  Then the filter function will be called.